# Find if a letter's are present inside a text in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, freetext

```
SELECT cat.CategoryId
  ,cat.CategoryImageURL
  ,cat.CategoryName
  ,cat.isDeleted
  ,ap.AppCreatedBy
  ,ap.AppCreatedOn
  ,ap.AppDetails
  ,ap.AppId
  ,ap.AppImageURL
  ,ap.AppModifiedBy
  ,ap.AppModifiedOn
  ,ap.AppName
  ,ap.isDeleted
  ,subcat.SubCategoryId
  ,subcat.SubCategoryName
  ,subcat.SubCategoryImageUrl
FROM Category cat
INNER JOIN App ap
  ON cat.CategoryID = ap.CategoryID
INNER JOIN SubCategory subcat
  ON subcat.SubCategoryId = ap.SubCategoryId
WHERE FREETEXT (
    cat.CategoryName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR FREETEXT (
    subcat.SubCategoryName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR FREETEXT (
    ap.AppName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR CONTAINS (
    ap.AppDetails
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR CONTAINS (
    cat.CategoryName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR CONTAINS (
    subcat.SubCategoryName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR CONTAINS (
    ap.AppName
    ,@searchparameter
    )
  OR CONTAINS (
    ap.AppDetails
    ,@searchparameter
    )

USE [AppStore]
GO

DECLARE @return_value INT

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[IndianAppStore_Search] @searchparameter = N'wishpicker'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

In the AppName column in App table there is a row which contains wishpicker as an AppName 
i want to show this result even if the user writes only wish for the search query.

Is that possible with freetext or any other search algo in sql server?

Comment: Are you just looking to find rows where ap.AppName contains the phrase "wishpicker"?  That's WHERE ap.AppName LIKE '%wishpicker%'

Comment: i want to find it even if the user writes just 'wish'.

Comment: then ap.AppName LIKE '%' + @searchparameter + '%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on the LIKE keyword.  But in short...

```
WHERE (ap.AppName LIKE 'wish%')  -- Finds app names BEGINNING with wish
WHERE (ap.AppName LIKE '%wish%') -- Finds app names CONTAINING wish
WHERE (ap.AppName LIKE '%wish')  -- Finds app names ENDING with wish
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this condition?

```
OR (@searchparameter = 'wish' and ap.AppName = 'wishpicker')
```

Or, if the `AppName` field needs wildcards:

```
OR (@searchparameter = 'wish' and ap.AppName like '%wishpicker%')
```

Comment: that's not ideal for a search algorithm as my user is only entering a search keyword